# How to call alert after all ajax requests are done?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm making in code a few requests with JQuery and `get`. It looks like:

```
$.get('address1', function() { ... });
$.get('address2', function() { ... });
$.get('address3', function() { ... });

// This code should be runned when all 3 requests are finished
alert('Finished');
```

So, are there any ways to detect whether there is still processing request and run marked code only when all 3 requests are finished.

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can make use of [*deferred objects* <sup>[docs]</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) introduced in jQuery 1.5:

```
$.when(
    $.get('address1', function() { ... }),
    $.get('address2', function() { ... }),
    $.get('address3', function() { ... })
).then(function() {
    alert('Finished');
});
```

**Reference:** [`jQuery.when`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/)

The jQuery learning center has a nice [introduction to deferred objects / promises](http://learn.jquery.com/code-organization/deferreds/).

Comment: If calling of `get` is in splitted functions? Can I do something like: `$.when(function() {doRequest1(); doRequest2(); doRequest3();}).then(function(){...});` ?

Comment: @Ockonal: Just return the promise objects returned by `$.get`: `function() {return $.get(...)}`. Then you can do `$.when(doRequest1(), doRequest2(), doRequest3())...`. Have a look at the documentation and examples, deferred objects can be tricky to get the head around, but they are quite powerful.

Answer (score 2):

```
 var isFinished = [];

$.get('address1', function() { isFinshed.push["address1"]; allDone(); });
$.get('address2', function() { isFinshed.push["address2"]; allDone(); });
$.get('address3', function() { isFinshed.push["address3"]; allDone();});

var allDone = function(){
    if(isFinished.length < 3)return

    alert('Finished');
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var fin1 = false;
var fin2 = false;
var fin3 = false;

$.ajax({
  url: "address1",
  success: function(){
    fin1 = true;
    fnUpdate();
  }
});

$.ajax({
  url: "address2",
  success: function(){
    fin2 = true;
    fnUpdate();
  }
});

$.ajax({
  url: "address3",
  success: function(){
    fin3 = true;
    fnUpdate();
  }
});

function fnUpdate(){
  if(fin1 && fin2 && fin3){
    alert('fin');
  }
}
```

Comment: What if a request has an error? Then technically all three are "finished," but no alert is seen.

Comment: Of course you can add error callback and then you can do your own business logic to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var count = 0;
$.get('address1', function() { count++; ... });
$.get('address2', function() { count++; ... });
$.get('address3', function() { count++; ... });

var int = setInterval(function() {
    if (count === 3) {
        clearInterval(int);
        alert('done');
    }
}, 10);
```